# Most immediate CDN

Tags: cdn

I'm interested in the user experience effects of a near-instantly loading home page.

Are there CDNs specifically designed to serve tiny data, like a 500-byte HTML page, to the browser **as fast as possible** after it requests my URL?

Clarity edit:
 I'm looking for something that can reliably (consistent across time and geographic region) get 500 bytes to the browser in about 0.1 seconds or less after the URI has been requested. Google seems able to achieve things like this.

Comment: Unless you're actually writing the code for such a server, this question is not programming related and therefore off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is this an actual problem for you, or a purely theoretical question? Even over a poor connection with a very slow phone modem, 500 bytes is a trivial amount of data.

Comment: Actually the whole point of the question, as stated in the OP, is to serve 500 bytes AS FAST AS POSSIBLE -- not in the 0.5 to 2 seconds it typically takes to begin the transfer of any amount of data after a URI has been requested.

Comment: Before the CDN gets asked for the data there is some DNS resolution to be done which may take a while if the information isn't cached.

Comment: That is what this question is asking about.  Which CDN services, and CDNing use-practices result in the most immediate HTTP transactions of this type?  You could also make this question more specific by limiting to a certain geographic market of users, like "the United States".

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com)

Comment: looks like spam

Comment: It's not spam. CloudFlare is used by thousands of sites (probably because of it's freemium model), including several of mine.